# Validação de Campos em Swift

Tags: swift

Como fazer a validação de campos usando o Swift?
Eu pretendia fazer com Exception, mas acabo de pesquisar e encontrei que o Swift não tem Exceptions...

Eu gostaria de algo assim:

```
void onCadastrar(dados){

    try {

        validarNome(dados.nome)
        validarSenha(dados.senha)
        ...
        etc

    } catch(MinhaException erro){

        //Alert da mensagem de erro

    }

}
```

Isso é possível em SWift?

Comment: Fiquei contente em saber disto, aí as pessoas param de abusar do recurso que deveria ser usado só em situações excepcionais. O problema é que provavelmente as pessoas vão abusar de outra coisa. Eu não sei de recursos específicos de Swift mas o que aconteceu com o bom e velho `if`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade o Swift não possui um try catch, mas sim possui exceptions, conforme [documentação Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/index.html).

Como o @Maniero citou, mesmo nas linguagens que possui o recurso de try catch esse apenas deve ser usado em algumas situações.

Agora para realizar o que deseja indico também o bom e velho `if`.

Algo como:

```
if dadosValidos() {
    enviarDados()
} else {
    exibeMensagemErro()
}
```

Agora se você esta fazendo uma Framework para ser usado por terceiros, para capturar terá que checar com `if` e então lançar um `fatalError()` com a mensagem, mas isso força a parada da aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

pode tentar usar um tipo chamado guard

```
guard let nome = dados.nome { print(erro) return }
resto do codigo
```

ou se nao, usando if mesmo

```
if let nome = dados.nome{ codigo}
```

no caso, se for possível efetuar a atribuição significa que o campo nao esta nulo

era tipo isso que voce precisava ?

Answer (score 0):

Embora sejam recomendadas outras alternativas é possível fazer desta maneira sim, ja me fiz essa mesma pergunta utilizando este mesmo caso de validação de campos e resolvi da seguinte forma:

primeiro você pode fazer um enum para listar todo tipo de erro possível que irá ser retornado

```
enum ValidatingError: Error {
    case invalidName
    case invalidPassword
}
```

Faça uma extensão para especificar o retorno de cada erro

```
extension ValidatingError: LocalizedError {
   public var errorDescription: String? {
      switch self {
      case .invalidName:
         return NSLocalizedString("ERRO no nome", comment: "Coloque um nome com mais de 3 letras")
      case .invalidPassword:
         return NSLocalizedString("Erro na senha", comment: "A senha deve conter 6 ou mais caracteres")
      }
   }
}
```

Crie as funções de validação

```
func valida(_ nome: String) throws {
    if nome.count <= 3{
        throw ValidatingError.invalidName
    }
}

func valida(_ senha: String) throws {
    if senha.count <= 6{
        throw ValidatingError.invalidPassword
    }
}
```

E para chamar da maneira como você especificou é só chamar os métodos dentro e um do catch

```
func onCadastrar(dados: Dados){

    do {
        try valida(dados.nome)
        try valida(dados.senha)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```